# Add an event handler to selected range

Tags: javascript, jquery, office-js, jquery-events

I would like to add an event handler to the ranges or cells that a user select in a workbook: if the user selects **another** cell or range, some actions need to be undertaken systematically.

I am looking at [this reference](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/binding.bindingselectionchangedevent), but I don't know where to integrate the code into the whole add-in.

For instance, in my `Home.html`, i have

```
    <div id="content-main">
        <div class = "padding" id="message"></div>
        <div class="padding">
            <button class="ms-Button" id="button">Click me!</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is `Home.js`:

```
(function() {
    "use strict";

    Office.initialize = function(reason) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            app.initialize();
            $('#button').click(activateEventHandler);
        });
    };

    function onBindingSelectionChanged(eventArgs) {
        write(eventArgs.binding.id + " has been selected.");
    }
    function write(message) {
        document.getElementById('message').innerText += message;
    }

    function activateEventHandler() {
        Excel.run(function(ctx) {
            var selectedRange = ctx.workbook.getSelectedRange();
            selectedRange.addHandlerAsync(Office.EventType.BindingSelectionChanged, onBindingSelectionChanged); 
            return ctx.sync()
        }).then(function() {
            console.log("done");
        }).catch(function(error) {
            ...
            }
        });
    }        
})();
```

I would expect the button activates the listener. Then, each time the user selects another cell or range, a message is systematically appended to the task pane. However, the above code raises an error:

> Error: TypeError: selectedRange.addHandlerAsync is not a function

at the line `selectedRange.addHandlerAsync(...`.

Actually, I am not even sure this code should be structured like that... Does anyone know how to modify the code to achieve my task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of the error is that you are trying to call the function addHandlerAsync on a Range object. But handlers can only be added to Binding objects or the Document object. Which one you choose depends on exactly what you want to accomplish. In your case I think you're not trying to listen for selections at **specific** ranges, but actually to listen for selections **anywhere** in the document. So you would actually use the [DocumentSelectionChanged event](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/document.selectionchanged.event):

```
(function() {
    "use strict";

    Office.initialize = function(reason) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            app.initialize();
            $('#button').click(activateEventHandler);
        });
    };

    function onMySelectionChanged(eventArgs) {
        write(eventArgs.binding.id + " has been selected.");
        doStuffWithNewSelection();

    }
    function write(message) {
        document.getElementById('message').innerText += message;
    }

    function activateEventHandler(){
        Office.context.document.addHandlerAsync(Office.EventType.DocumentSelectionChanged, onMySelectionChanged);
    }

    function doStuffWithNewSelection() {
        Excel.run(function(ctx) {
            var selectedRange = ctx.workbook.getSelectedRange();
            // do other stuff with the selection as you wish, like read and display
        }).then(function() {
            console.log("done");
        }).catch(function(error) {
            ...
            }
        });
    }        
})();
```